# Getting a Spacy error: No module named 'spacy.pipeline.pipes'; 'spacy.pipeline' is not a package

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to test a model that is working in another machine, but when I try to import it to my notebook, I get this error: 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy.pipeline.pipes'; 'spacy.pipeline' is not a package

We have installed:
Spacy 2.0.18 (Frozen version, Not updatable whatsoever)

And I'm importing:

```
import spacy
import thinc
import unidecode
import nltk
from spacy.vocab    import Vocab
from spacy.language import Language
from spacy.lang.pt  import Portuguese
from spacy.lang.en  import English
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRecognizer
ner = EntityRecognizer(nlp.vocab)
nlp = Language(Vocab())
nlp = Portuguese()
# Load NER Model
NER_MODEL = pickle.load( open("/ner_model_v022_epoch=706_loss=09o76364626.pkl", "rb" ) )
```

And I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-83d4770d3e3e> in <module>

---> 40 NER_MODEL = pickle.load( open("/ner_model_v022_epoch=706_loss=09o76364626.pkl", "rb" ) )

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy.pipeline.pipes'; 'spacy.pipeline' is not a package
```

Any ideas why this might be happening? Already installed everything again from 0 but keeps giving me the same error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the model you are trying to load was created using a different version of spaCy... Could you make sure that is not the case?

Comment: I got the same issue. Just close the terminal (console) window and re-open it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem come up and found that switching my spacy version from `spacy==2.0.18` to `spacy==2.1.4` worked! Went back through their releases and spacy.pipeline.pipes isn't present until [v2.1.0a8](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/tree/v2.1.0a8)

Answer (score 3):

Close and re-open the Terminal (console). 
Activate the `venv` from the current folder you're working on.

Comment: I applied your solution and it worked for me.

Do you know how to explain why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

If you tried to install it via github and you still have that folder, it could cause issues. For me, deleting the spaCy folder helped.